# Internationalized Wizard Passing model data between the wizard steps

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, wizard

I've found the following example of a wizard located here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF

Now I've spent quite some time looking at the example and i understand pretty much everything. But i can't figure out how he passes an object between the different modelViews.
And as you can imagine that step is quite crucial..

In the example he uses an CupOfCoffee Object in the main wizardviewmodel and somehow manages to adjust it throughout the wizard. But i cant see anywhere how he does that.

I've already tried to recreate a project like he has but no success.

Could anyone tell me how he passes the objects between the different viewModels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a wild guess:

in `CreatePages()` he is initializing each pageviewmodel with `this.CupOfCoffee` which seems to be the model.

you do know that you can download the complete source code at codeproject?

Comment: Yes i know, and I've been staring at it for the past few hours, but he passes the object byvalue and not byreference

Comment: why do you assume that? this is a pass by reference!

Comment: just got a great lesson between the difference of referencetypes and value types... still a bit confused about what the byval is for then, rather confusing. but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`CupOfCoffee` is shared accross all ViewModels through `CoffeeWizardViewModel`, which drives the entire wizzard.

It keeps "global" state and the other ViewModels inheriting from `CoffeeWizzardPageViewModelBase` that contain only the logic for one page each.

Comment: But when setting the cupofcoffee object in a wizard step view, it sets the coffeeobject of CoffeeWizzardPageViewModelBase, but how does he get the data from CoffeeWizzardPageViewModelBase to CoffeeWizardViewModel?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, had to pick one but this answer is just as good. didn't know the difference between reference types and value types. i thought byval always gave a value and never a reference.